# Java Maven project won't build & get deployed to Heroku

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, heroku, pom.xml

I'm quite new to both Heroku & Java EE projects. I'm trying to test a simple RESTful web app in Java & deploy it on Heroku.

It's creating an app, but it's not building it, neither is it deploying it. I suspect there's something I am missing. I looked around a bit in StackOverflow, the couldn't figure out anything from the posts.

I created a simple Java Maven project following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=skltzZH7i4w&index=11&list=PLqq-6Pq4lTTZh5U8RbdXq0WaYvZBz2rbn)
 tutorial here on YouTube!

Then I tried following [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-java-applications-to-heroku-from-eclipse-or-intellij-idea) tutorial here for deployment on my app & this is where things went wrong.

Running the `pom.xml` as Maven Build is throwing the following error in the console

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml (13 KB at 5.8 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml (20 KB at 8.0 KB/sec)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.283 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-08-06T22:37:59+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/208M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'heroku' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/home/stpl/.m2/repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoPluginFoundForPrefixException
```

Following is my `pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.auro.self</groupId>
  <artifactId>auromovieshelf</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>auromovieshelf</name>
  <properties>
    <jersey.version>2.23.1</jersey.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxrs-ri</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-guava</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-jsr166e</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.connectors</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-apache-connector</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.connectors</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-grizzly-connector</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.connectors</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-jetty-connector</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-jetty-http</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-grizzly2-http</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-grizzly2-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-jetty-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-jdk-http</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-simple-http</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-gf-ejb</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-bean-validation</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-entity-filtering</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-metainf-services</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-mvc</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-mvc-bean-validation</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-mvc-freemarker</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-mvc-jsp</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-mvc-mustache</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-proxy-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-servlet-portability</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-declarative-linking</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-wadl-doclet</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-weld2-se</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-cdi1x</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-cdi1x-transaction</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-cdi1x-validation</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-cdi1x-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-cdi1x-ban-custom-hk2-binding</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext.rx</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-rx-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext.rx</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-rx-client-guava</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext.rx</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-rx-client-java8</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext.rx</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-rx-client-jsr166e</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext.rx</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-rx-client-rxjava</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-jaxb</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>html-json</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson1</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jettison</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-processing</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-kryo</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-sse</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>oauth1-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>oauth1-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>oauth1-signature</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>oauth2-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-bundle</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.1</version>
        <type>pom</type>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-external</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-grizzly2</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-inmemory</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-jdk-http</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-simple</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-jetty</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-util</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.1</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.23.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <releases>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>/home/stpl/WORKSPACE/EclipseWorkspace/auromovieshelf/src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <scriptSourceDirectory>/home/stpl/WORKSPACE/EclipseWorkspace/auromovieshelf/src/main/scripts</scriptSourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>/home/stpl/WORKSPACE/EclipseWorkspace/auromovieshelf/src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
    <outputDirectory>/home/stpl/WORKSPACE/EclipseWorkspace/auromovieshelf/target/classes</outputDirectory>
    <testOutputDirectory>/home/stpl/WORKSPACE/EclipseWorkspace/auromovieshelf/target/test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>/home/stpl/WORKSPACE/EclipseWorkspace/auromovieshelf/src/main/resources</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
      <testResource>
        <directory>/home/stpl/WORKSPACE/EclipseWorkspace/auromovieshelf/src/test/resources</directory>
      </testResource>
    </testResources>
    <directory>/home/stpl/WORKSPACE/EclipseWorkspace/auromovieshelf/target</directory>
    <finalName>auromovieshelf</finalName>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.3</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.3.2</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-compile</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <source>1.7</source>
              <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-testCompile</id>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <source>1.7</source>
              <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <inherited>true</inherited>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-clean</id>
            <phase>clean</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>clean</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-testResources</id>
            <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testResources</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-resources</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>resources</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-war</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>war</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-test</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-install</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>install</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-site</id>
            <phase>site</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>site</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>/home/stpl/WORKSPACE/EclipseWorkspace/auromovieshelf/target/site</outputDirectory>
              <reportPlugins>
                <reportPlugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                </reportPlugin>
              </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>site-deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>/home/stpl/WORKSPACE/EclipseWorkspace/auromovieshelf/target/site</outputDirectory>
              <reportPlugins>
                <reportPlugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                </reportPlugin>
              </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>/home/stpl/WORKSPACE/EclipseWorkspace/auromovieshelf/target/site</outputDirectory>
          <reportPlugins>
            <reportPlugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
            </reportPlugin>
          </reportPlugins>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <reporting>
    <outputDirectory>/home/stpl/WORKSPACE/EclipseWorkspace/auromovieshelf/target/site</outputDirectory>
  </reporting>
</project>
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: looks like the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/q/30279769/4311135

Answer (score 0):

try to add heroku pluging in your pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

You're missing this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.heroku.sdk</groupId>
    <artifactId>heroku-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.3</version>
</plugin>
```

See [Deploying Java Applications with the Heroku Maven Plugin](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-java-applications-with-the-heroku-maven-plugin)